# error in range() (python 2)

Tags: python, debugging, range

When I type this code:

```
n = raw_input()
x = raw_input()
y = raw_input()
z = []
seats = x.split(" ")
onoff = y.split(" ")
for i in range(1, n):
    if onoff[i] == 1:
        z.append(seats[i])

z.sort()
a = ""
for i in range(1, len(z)):
    a += str(z[i]) + " "

print a
```

I get this error:

```
     for i in range(1, n):
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got str.
```

can anybody tell what's the problem with this?
thanks.

Comment: n = int(raw_input()) input collects a string object, you need to use an integer object in range.

Comment: `raw_input` returns a string, not an integer. You should manually convert it with `n = int(raw_input)`

Comment: This error message is very self-explanatory. `n` is string but `range` expects `int` arguments. `n = int(raw_input())`

Answer (score 2):

```
n=raw_input()
```

any thing read using raw_input will be treated as string using python
so you need to type cast it to int

```
n=int(raw_input())
```

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input()` returns a `string` and not an `integer`, you can use `input()` if you are using python 2 or `int(raw_input())` One more thing, in python 2, I advise you to use `xrange()` instead of `range()`

Answer (score 0):

raw_input will give you a string value not an int value at default. A long as n is input as an int you can use

```
for i in range(1, int(n)):
    if onoff[i] == 1:
        z.append(seats[i])
```